# how do I upload multiple files to firebase databse in order as in arraylist?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm trying to add multiple images to firebase, but it seems like it doesn't upload in order. I believe myUrlList gets added depending on the order of getting uploaded to the server. Is there any way I can sort myUrlsList same as imageUrlList?

```
    for(int i=0; i< imageUriList.size(); i++){
            final StorageReference filereference = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                    + "." + getFileExtension(imageUriList.get(i)));

            uploadTask = filereference.putFile(imageUriList.get(i));
            uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation() {
                @Override
                public Object then(@NonNull Task task) throws Exception {
                    if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                        throw task.getException();
                    }

                    return filereference.getDownloadUrl();
                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){

                        Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                        myUrl = downloadUri.toString();
                        myUrlList.add(myUrl);
```

Comment: If you want ordering, you'll have to wait to start the next upload after the first one completes.  What you have now uploads everything in parallel, with no ordering guarantee.

Comment: What would be the options for waiting to start the next upload after the one completes?

Comment: I mean is task.isSuccessful the place where it causes the problem?

Comment: further question my for loop happens after addOnCompleteListener. How is it possible that myUrlList gets added parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you are using a loop and theoretically, the upload of the images should be in the order of the iteration, you cannot know how much it will take to actually upload each image to the Firebase Storage separately. As @DougStevenson mentioned in his comment, you are uploading everything in "parallel". So an image of a smaller size can be uploaded much faster than an image of a bigger size, even if the smaller image is positioned right after the larger image, as it will take a smaller amount of time to be uploaded.

The solution to solve this issue is to wait until an image is uploaded and start the next upload, right after the upload of the previous image completes. This is typically done with recursion, with a method that invokes itself.

```
private void uploadImageToFirebaseStorage() {
    if (imageUriList.size() > 0) {
        Uri imageUri = imageUriList.get(0);
        StorageReference filereference = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                + "." + getFileExtension(imageUri));
        imageUriList.remove(0);
        uploadTask = filereference.putFile(imageUri);
        uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation() {
            @Override
            public Object then(@NonNull Task task) throws Exception {
                if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                    throw task.getException();
                }

                return filereference.getDownloadUrl();
            }
        }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                    myUrl = downloadUri.toString();
                    myUrlList.add(myUrl);
                    uploadBeerImageToFirebaseStorage(); //Call when completes
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

First, kick it off with `uploadImageToFirebaseStorage()`. Once an image is uploaded, the method will check if there's more work that should be done, and reinvokes itself if that's the case.

Comment: is there reason why you called it a uploadbeerimagetofirebasestorage when its supposed to be recursion?

Comment: The recursion is the way the method is invoked. If you want, you can change the name of the method to `uploadImageToFirebaseStorageRecursive()`, or you can choose any other name you want.

Answer (score 0):

get the name from arraylist create new handler and execute runnable, Now every time when upload execute it create new runnable for different file and then upload file as your requirement.