# Unable to dismiss the progressdialog inside the addonsucesslistener() which is inside "for loop"

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage, progressdialog

I'm selecting multiple images and storing them into Firebase Storage, and retrieving the download URL inside an ArrayList and adding it into the Firebase Database, my code is working fine but I don't know when to stop the progress dialog, where I have to dismiss the progress dialog so when the task of the progress bar is completed than progress dialog disappear.

Here is my code:

```
private void uploadScreenshot() {

    if (screenshotUri != null) {
        final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mDialog.setMessage("Uploading...");
        mDialog.show();

        String ssName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        final StorageReference screenshotFolder = storageReference.child("screenshots/" + ssName);

        for (upload_count = 0; upload_count < ScreenshotList.size(); upload_count++) {
            Uri IndividualImage = Uri.parse(ScreenshotList.get(upload_count));
            final StorageReference ScreenshotName = screenshotFolder.child(IndividualImage.getLastPathSegment());

            ScreenshotName.putFile(IndividualImage).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    ScreenshotName.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            String url = String.valueOf(uri);
                            storeLink(url);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(AppList.this, "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
                    .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                            mDialog.setMessage("Uploaded " + progress + "%");
                        }
                    });
        }

    }
    // mDialog.dismiss();
    //Toast.makeText(AppList.this, "Screenshots Uploaded !!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


private void storeLink(String url) {


    ssList.add(url);

    newApp.setScreenshot(ssList);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the `uploadScreenshot()` the first thing you do is to display a ProgressDialog. When you upload a file to Firebase Storage, the response that you get can be either a success or a failure, never both. This means that you should dismiss the dialog in both onSuccess() and onFailure() methods. If you have successfully uploaded the file, the dialog should be dismissed, as it also should be if you get a failure. So please add the following lines of code:

```
mDialog.dismiss();
```

Inside onSuccess() and onFailure() methods.

**Edit:**

If you want to dismiss the dialog only after uploading all files, then you should use recursion as explained in my answer from the following post:

- [how do I upload multiple files to firebase databse in order as in arraylist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60443829/how-do-i-upload-multiple-files-to-firebase-databse-in-order-as-in-arraylist/)

This means that when the size of the list becomes zero, you can dismiss the dialog.

Comment: as you can see that add.onsucceslistener and onfailure is inside for loop , so whenever the for loop is called again the dialog would dismissed , i need to dismiss the dialog after uploading all selected pics .@Alex Mamo

Comment: In that case, please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks @Alex , I'm able to store multiple images using recursion but one problem is occured when i again try store some images in storage , the previous stored images urls also coming together at the time of retreiving

Comment: In general, other questions that derive from the initial question should be considered new questions and should be added separately. So please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Thanks@Alex Mamo

Answer (score 0):

replace   **mDialog.dismiss();**  after the addprogressListner in your code

```html
private void uploadScreenshot() {

        if (screenshotUri != null) {
            final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mDialog.setMessage("Uploading...");
            mDialog.show();

            String ssName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            final StorageReference screenshotFolder = storageReference.child("screenshots/" + ssName);

            for (upload_count = 0; upload_count < ScreenshotList.size(); upload_count++) {
                Uri IndividualImage = Uri.parse(ScreenshotList.get(upload_count));
                final StorageReference ScreenshotName = screenshotFolder.child(IndividualImage.getLastPathSegment());

                ScreenshotName.putFile(IndividualImage).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        ScreenshotName.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                String url = String.valueOf(uri);
                                storeLink(url);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        mDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(AppList.this, "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                        .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                                mDialog.setMessage("Uploaded " + progress + "%");
                            }
                        });
                    mDialog.dismiss();
Toast.makeText(AppList.this, "Screenshots Uploaded !!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }

        }
        
        
    }


    private void storeLink(String url) {


        ssList.add(url);

        newApp.setScreenshot(ssList);
    }
```

Comment: I commented this line because it is in wrong place @viranga