# How to manage memory when downloading multiple files from firebase in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have an images directory in Firebase Storage and I am trying to download all the files in that directory to my app. each image has a corresponding field in the database that stores its name the downloads are mostly successful but the app freezes and gets an App Not Responding prompt when you try to interact with ui or crashes after a while when you just wait.

below is the code I use to download the images to my app's storage directory

```
private void downloadAllTopicsAndFirstItems(Activity activity) {
    databaseReference.child(FIREBASE_TOPIC_NODE).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            int count = 0;
            for (DataSnapshot snap : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                Topic topic = snap.getValue(Topic.class);
                if (topic == null) return;
                if (topic.getItems() != null) topic.setTotalItems(topic.getItems().size());
                File fileTopic = new File(activity.getFilesDir(), topic.getFirebaseImageNode() + ".jpg");
                Topic topic1 = new Topic();
                LiveData<Topic> topicWithId = viewModel.getTopicWithId(topic.getId());
                topicWithId.observe((LifecycleOwner) activity, topic2 -> {
                    if (topic2 != null) {
                        topic1.setId(topic2.getId());
                        topic1.setFirebaseImageNode(topic2.getFirebaseImageNode());
                        topic1.setImageUrl(topic2.getImageUrl());
                        topic1.setTitle(topic2.getTitle());
                        topic1.setDescription(topic2.getDescription());
                        topicWithId.removeObservers((LifecycleOwner) activity);
                    }
                });
                if (!fileTopic.exists()) {
                    int finalCount = count;
                    storageReference.child(FIREBASE_APP_IMAGES).child(topic.getFirebaseImageNode() + ".jpg")
                            .getFile(fileTopic)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot -> {
                                topic.setLocalStorageUri(fileTopic.getAbsolutePath());
                                if (finalCount <6) getTopicItems(topic.getItems(), activity);
                                if (topic.equals(topic1)) viewModel.updateTopic(topic);
                                else viewModel.insertTopics(topic);
                                Log.d("Topic Image", "onSuccess: downloaded to " + fileTopic.getAbsolutePath());
                            })
                            .addOnFailureListener(e -> Log.d("Topic Image", "onFailure: " + topic.getFirebaseImageNode() + ".jpg" + e.toString()));
                } else {
                    topic.setLocalStorageUri(fileTopic.getAbsolutePath());
                    if (count<6) getTopicItems(topic.getItems(), activity);
                    if (topic.equals(topic1)) viewModel.updateTopic(topic);
                    else viewModel.insertTopics(topic);
                }

                topics.add(topic);
                viewModel.insertTopics(topic);
                Log.d("Topic ", topic.toString());
                count++;
                if (topics.size() == snapshot.getChildrenCount()) {
                    Log.d("Topics", "onDataChange: " + topics.toString());
                    topicRvAdapter.setItems(topics);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            if (error.getCode() == DatabaseError.DISCONNECTED) {
                errorView.setText(R.string.no_internet);
            } else {
                errorView.setText(R.string.something_went_wrong);
            }
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
}
```

The method below downloads the items contained in a single topic. *Note: Some topics have over 200 items*

```
private void getTopicItems(ArrayList<Item> items, Activity activity){
    if (items != null) {
        for (Item item : items) {
            Item item1 = new Item();
            LiveData<Item> itemWithId = viewModel.getItemWithId(item.getId());
            itemWithId.observe((LifecycleOwner) activity, item2 -> {
                if (item2 != null) {
                    item1.setId(item2.getId());
                    item1.setImageUrl(item2.getImageUrl());
                    item1.setEnglishWord(item2.getEnglishWord());
                    item1.setCategory(item2.getCategory());
                    item1.setTopic(item2.getTopic());
                    item1.setRutooroWord(item2.getRutooroWord());
                    item1.setFirebaseImageNode(item2.getFirebaseImageNode());
                    itemWithId.removeObservers((LifecycleOwner) activity);

                }
            });
            // download the item image to storage;
            String itemNode = item.getFirebaseImageNode();
            File file = new File(activity.getFilesDir(), itemNode + ".jpg");
            if (itemNode != null) {
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    storageReference.child(FIREBASE_APP_IMAGES).child(itemNode + ".jpg")
                            .getFile(file)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot -> {
                                item.setLocalStorageUri(file.getAbsolutePath());
                                if (item.equals(item1)) viewModel.updateItem(item);
                                else viewModel.insertItems(item);
                                Log.d("Topic Item Image", "onSuccess: downloaded to " + file.getAbsolutePath());
                            })
                            .addOnFailureListener(e -> Log.d("Topic Item Image", "onFailure: " + itemNode + ".jpg" + e.toString()));
                } else {
                    item.setLocalStorageUri(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    if (item.equals(item1)) viewModel.updateItem(item);
                    else viewModel.insertItems(item);
                }
            } else {
                if (item.equals(item1)) viewModel.updateItem(item);
                else viewModel.insertItems(item);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

After a minute or two the app crashes with the error below

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.allez.san.myapplication, PID: 18718
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 24 byte allocation with 2000472 free bytes and 1953KB until OOM, target footprint 201326592, growth limit 201326592; failed due to fragmentation (largest possible contiguous allocation 150470656 bytes)
        at java.lang.reflect.Executable.getMethodOrConstructorGenericInfoInternal(Executable.java:708)
        at java.lang.reflect.Executable.getGenericParameterTypes(Executable.java:270)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericParameterTypes(Method.java:212)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:588)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:563)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(CustomClassMapper.java:433)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:232)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToType(CustomClassMapper.java:179)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToParameterizedType(CustomClassMapper.java:246)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToType(CustomClassMapper.java:177)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$100(CustomClassMapper.java:48)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:593)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:563)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(CustomClassMapper.java:433)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:232)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(CustomClassMapper.java:80)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:203)
        at com.allez.san.learnrutooro.utils.DownloadUtil$3.onDataChange(DownloadUtil.java:296)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8512)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1139)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 18718 SIG: 9
```

Comment: How many images do you have in that directory?

Comment: As I mentioned above some items have over 200 images so a rough estimate would be around 1000 images

Comment: Try to use a [recursive method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60443829/how-do-i-upload-multiple-files-to-firebase-databse-in-order-as-in-arraylist/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're downloading all files in parallel, which means that memory consumption is going to go up as the number of files goes up. To limit the memory consumption, download the files one by one, or with a reasonable maximum number of parallel downloads.

Comment: I thought 'storageReference.getFile()' api downloads the files on different threads. if so is there a way for me to manage this behavour better.

Comment: It doesn't really matter where the download happens: as long as they all happen in parallel, the memory usage will go up with the number of files you download. The solution is to limit how many files you download in parallel. The simplest way to do this would be to only start on the next file once the current file is completed, for example by keeping a list of the items left to download and then checking if there are more items to download after the current one completes.