# I'm uploading multiple images to Firebase and it's completed, but I can't save the url link to a list

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage

I'm uploading multiple images to Firebase and it's completed, but I can't save the URL link to a list.

```
private fun uploadAllImage(imageList: MutableList<Uri>) {
    val storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("image")
    val storeImage = mutableListOf<Uri>()

    for (i in imageList) {

        val indImg = i
        var imageName = storageReference.child("Image" + indImg.lastPathSegment)

        imageName.putFile(indImg).addOnSuccessListener {
            binding.userImage.setImageURI(null)
            imageName.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
                Log.d("image", it.toString())
                storeImage.add(it)
            }
        }
    }

    Log.d("imageList", storeImage.size.toString())
}
```

Comment: can u see the log message being printed in logcat?

Answer (score 0):

try out on complete listener callback like this

```
imageName.putFile(indImg).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
    if (task.isSuccessful) {
        val downloadUrl = task.result.toString()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling the `.putFile()` method, it means that you are performing an asynchronous operation. Remember, that it takes time to actually upload a file to Firebase Storage. So any code that needs to process data related to that operation, needs to be added inside the `onSuccess()` method, or be called from there. So you have to move the following line of code:

```
Log.d("imageList", storeImage.size.toString())
```

Inside the callback, to actually know when a single upload is complete.

However, when you add multiple files in parallel, you'll never know when all uploads are completed, unless you perform an upload operation right after another. This can be done using a recursion (a function that invokes itself). So please try to use my answer from the following post:

- [how do I upload multiple files to firebase databse in order as in arraylist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60443829/how-do-i-upload-multiple-files-to-firebase-databse-in-order-as-in-arraylist/)

It's Java code but can be really simple converted into Kotlin.