# Firebase E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred. Object does not exist at location

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload 4 different images to firebase storage, my code works with a single image, but whenever I try to upload multiple images I get

```
 E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    Object does not exist at location.
     Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
2021-11-18 22:45:16.584 com.example.test E/StorageException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found."  }}
    java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found."  }}
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(NetworkRequest.java:445)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(NetworkRequest.java:462)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(NetworkRequest.java:453)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:272)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:289)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:76)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:68)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.GetDownloadUrlTask.run(GetDownloadUrlTask.java:77)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

This is my code to upload images to firebase storage and even after getting errors, I can see the images on firebase Storage but I am getting the error on the app.

```
private synchronized void UploadToFireBaseStorage(ArrayList<String> filePath,int type) {
        
        final ArrayList<String> multipleImages = new ArrayList<>();
        Log.d(TAG,"Size of File at Upload Method "+filePath.size());

        if (filePath.size()==0){
            return;
        }

        
        Uri fileUri = null;

        for (String s : filePath) {
            if (s.contains(".jpg")) {
                    fileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(s));
                } else {
                    fileUri = Uri.parse(s);
                }

            
            StorageReference mStorageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
            Log.d(TAG, "UploadToFireBaseStorage: StorageRef "+mStorageReference);

           
            storageReference = mStorageReference.child("Photos").child(fileUri.getLastPathSegment());
           
            Log.d(TAG, "UploadToFireBaseStorage: Storage Reference "+storageReference);
            Log.d(TAG, "UploadToFireBaseStorage: File URI = "+fileUri);
            String finalAttachmentType = attachmentType;
            String finalUploadFolder = uploadFolder;
            storageReference.putFile(fileUri).addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(@NonNull Uri uri) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Image Uploaded ");
                            Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: URI Uploaded == "+uri);
                            
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    double progress = 100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / (double) taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Upload is " + progress + "% done");
                    

                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: "+s);
                    
                }
            });
        }
        Log.d(TAG,"Image List "+multipleImages.toString());
    }
```

These are the storage reference i got for 4 different images

```
Storage Reference gs://example-89902.appspot.com/Photos/Image%20IMG_1637256617899.jpg

Storage Reference gs://example-89902.appspot.com/Photos/Image%20IMG_1637256617949.jpg

Storage Reference gs://example-89902.appspot.com/Photos/Image%20IMG_1637256618132.jpg

Storage Reference gs://example-89902.appspot.com/Photos/Image%20IMG_1637256618070.jpg
```

Firebase Storage Rules:

```
Firebase Storage Rules
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/bucket/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does `Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: URI Uploaded == "+uri);` log the corect URIs?

Comment: @AlexMamo If i am uploading 4 then it shows for 2 images and for the othera 2 it just shows error i mentioned above

Comment: I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60443829/how-do-i-upload-multiple-files-to-firebase-databse-in-order-as-in-arraylist) will help. Does it?

Comment: @AlexMamo Thanks for the suggestion but my method is `synchronized`  does it work? or if not then any suggestion for how to synchronized upload process?

Comment: @AlexMamo i don't have any issue with order of uploads and you can also see i am only doing something with image when i get into on upload success. Can you please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

According to the stack trace the problem seems to be related to obtaining the download url:

```
at com.google.firebase.storage.GetDownloadUrlTask.run(GetDownloadUrlTask.java:77)
```

It's probably caused by this code fragment:

```java
@Override
public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

  storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(@NonNull Uri uri) {
          Log.d(TAG, "Image Uploaded ");
          Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: URI Uploaded == "+uri);
          
      }
  });
  
}
```

My guess is that there is some kind of race condition between the upload success callback and the instant in which the storage reference and the corresponding download url are available.

As suggested in the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files), please, try modifying your code like this in order to obtain the download url:

```java
private synchronized void UploadToFireBaseStorage(ArrayList<String> filePath,int type) {
        
    final ArrayList<String> multipleImages = new ArrayList<>();
    Log.d(TAG,"Size of File at Upload Method "+filePath.size());

    if (filePath.size()==0){
        return;
    }

    
    Uri fileUri = null;

    for (String s : filePath) {
        if (s.contains(".jpg")) {
                fileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(s));
            } else {
                fileUri = Uri.parse(s);
            }

        
        StorageReference mStorageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        Log.d(TAG, "UploadToFireBaseStorage: StorageRef "+mStorageReference);

        
        storageReference = mStorageReference.child("Photos").child(fileUri.getLastPathSegment());
        
        Log.d(TAG, "UploadToFireBaseStorage: Storage Reference "+storageReference);
        Log.d(TAG, "UploadToFireBaseStorage: File URI = "+fileUri);
        String finalAttachmentType = attachmentType;
        String finalUploadFolder = uploadFolder;
        UploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(fileUri).addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                // The stuff you considerd appropriate
                Log.d(TAG, "Image Uploaded ");
            }
        }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                double progress = 100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / (double) taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                Log.d(TAG, "Upload is " + progress + "% done");
                

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: "+s);
                
            }
        });

        uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
            @Override
            public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    throw task.getException();
                }

                // Continue with the task to get the download URL
                return ref.getDownloadUrl();
            }
        }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: URI Uploaded == "+downloadUri);
                } else {
                    // Handle failures
                    // ...
                }
            }
        });
    }
    Log.d(TAG,"Image List "+multipleImages.toString());
}
```

Previously `UploadTask.TaskSnapshot` had a `getDownloadUrl()` method, but it is no longer available. The subject has been discussed in different issues like [this one](https://github.com/udacity/and-nd-firebase/issues/41), for instance, which provides further alternatives as well.

---

As a side note, and probably unrelated, but certainly curious, you pointed out in your comments that two of the images are uploaded successfully and two not. As you can see in the [source code of `Uploadtask`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/5bc0fefbfa11256f4760ce0e1972ef604925c9e6/firebase-storage/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/storage/UploadTask.java#L196-L199), this kind of tasks are scheduled using the following code:

```java
@Override
protected void schedule() {
  StorageTaskScheduler.getInstance().scheduleUpload(getRunnable());
}
```

[`StorageTaskScheduler`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/5bc0fefbfa11256f4760ce0e1972ef604925c9e6/firebase-storage/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageTaskScheduler.java#L44-L46) schedules uploads in a thread pool executor of a maximum of two threads:

```java
private static final ThreadPoolExecutor UPLOAD_QUEUE_EXECUTOR =
    new ThreadPoolExecutor(
        2, 2, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, mUploadQueue, new StorageThreadFactory("Upload-"));
```

Maybe some uploads are being blocked by this thread pool as you are trying uploading a greater number of images that the available number of threads.

In contrast, the operation for obtaining the download url is performed in a different [thread pool](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/5bc0fefbfa11256f4760ce0e1972ef604925c9e6/firebase-storage/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageTaskScheduler.java#L39-L41):

```java
private static final ThreadPoolExecutor COMMAND_POOL_EXECUTOR =
    new ThreadPoolExecutor(
        5, 5, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, mCommandQueue, new StorageThreadFactory("Command-"));
```

As you can see, in this pool the number of threads is five and it means there is enough room to submit the get download task operations.

I reviewed the code and cannot find any leak, but it is certain that this difference may be related to your problem in any way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried code in documentation as mentioned but i am still getting same 'object not found error' as in ques

Comment: You are welcome @androidXP. Thank you very much for the feedback. That is strange indeed. Did you removed the code fragment `storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(@NonNull Uri uri) {
          Log.d(TAG, "Image Uploaded ");
          Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: URI Uploaded == "+uri);
          
      }
  });`  from your `UploadTask` `OnSuccessListener` callback? Even then, the error still exists?

Comment: yes and at `addOnCompleteListener`  the `task.isSuccessful()` is false 2 times as before and true 2 times when i upload 4 images together. then it gives me same error i mentioned above.

Comment: But as i can check the code you mentioned is also a official code but the other link you mentioned from github has some code which i tried and strange this code `@Override
public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
     Task<Uri> urlTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
     while (!urlTask.isSuccessful());
     Uri downloadUrl = urlTask.getResult();
     FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage = new FriendlyMessage(null, mUsername, downloadUrl.toString());
     mDatabaseReference.push().setValue(friendlyMessage);
}` work perfectly. Can you please explain why?

Comment: what the  `while (!urlTask.isSuccessful());`  works not `if else`

Comment: Hi @androidXP. That is very strange, the problem with the original code I mean. At least, I am happy to hear that some options in the companion link are working properly. Regarding why it works with the `while` loop, as you can see in the [source code of StorageReference](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/5bc0fefbfa11256f4760ce0e1972ef604925c9e6/firebase-storage/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference.java#L358-L372), when you invoke `getDownloadUrl` a new task is scheduled. The `while` loop is causing the code to block until a valid result is available

Comment: it could be an option indeed, although please, be aware that it can cause some problems: think about what will happen if a successful result is never obtained, your application will block indefinitely. Internally an exponential backoff algorithm is used to actually perform the task, but even in that case it can be a problem. If you decide to use that option try providing some kind of guard, let's say for instance a counter, to prevent this kind of possible infinite loop. I do not know whether you have the ability or not to `sleep` the thread here, maybe it can have some impact in the app UI