# Uploading List of images to Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I'm working on an android application where there is a need to upload multiple images to firebase storage and get their download URLs in an arraylist.

> uriList - ArrayList containing URIs of images to be uploaded
> urlList - ArrayList of downloadUrls of uploaded images

I have tried this-

```
fun uploadImages(urisList:ArrayList<Uri>) :ArrayList<String>
{
    val urlList = ArrayList<String>()
    val mainReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("images")
    for(uri in urisList)
    {
        val ref = mainReference.child(uri.lastPathSegment.toString())
        ref.putFile(uri).addOnCompleteListener{ imageUploadTask->
            if(imageUploadTask.isSuccessful)
            {
                ref.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { imageUrlUri->
                    urlList.add(imageUrlUri.toString())
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //code to handle failure of image uploading
        }
    }
    return urlList
}
```

but this uploads all images but `urlList` always contains only one item.

Then tried another recursive Solution-

```
fun uploadImages(urlList: ArrayList<String>, uriList: ArrayList<Uri>, index: Int = 0) {
    val mainReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("images")
    if (index != uriList.size) {
        val ref = mainReference.child(uriList[index].lastPathSegment.toString())
        ref.putFile(uriList[index]).addOnCompleteListener { imageUploadTask ->
            if (imageUploadTask.isSuccessful) {
                ref.downloadUrl.addOnCompleteListener { imageUrlUri ->
                    urlList.add(imageUrlUri.toString())
                    uploadImages(urlList, uriList, index + 1)
                }
            } else {
                    uploadImages(urlList, uriList, index + 1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(index to keep track of which image to be uploaded)
this recursive solution is working, but I think that it is not a good way to use **recursive** solution do this task.

---

Please help me to do this task in better way(either using coroutines or something other).

Comment: What's wrong with that recursive solution? Have tried [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60443829/how-do-i-upload-multiple-files-to-firebase-databse-in-order-as-in-arraylist/)?

Answer (score 0):

ref.putFile returns a task
You can run the whole opertaion serially on one single thread like this

```
AsyncTask.execute(()->{
                    for(...){
                        UploadTask task = (..).putFile(..)
                        com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.await(task)
                    }
                    //All tasks completed serially,proceed next
                });
```